# Increase storage capacity of hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

we have 5 node cluster with following configurations for master and slaves.

```
HDPMaster   35 GB   500 GB
HDPSlave1   15 GB   500 GB
HDPSlave2   15 GB   500 GB
HDPSlave3   15 GB   500 GB
HDPSlave4   15 GB   500 GB
HDPSlave5   15 GB   500 GB
```

But the cluster is not taking much space. I am aware of the fact that it will reserve some space for non-dfs use.But,it is taking uneven capacity for each slave node. Is there a way to reconfigure hdfs ?

PFA.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85rPUe3-QPXVV83MUhzX2JsZm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use the builtin image upload, not Google Drive

Comment: I tried it but its not working for me.